# Filters as rewrite results link path parameters

Tags: 8, views, navigation

I am currently using this approach to link lists view's rows to detail pages in Drupal 8

[image: The Rewrite Output as a customer link]

I would like to pass the entity title of the row to the receiving page and use that to select view blocks having that title.

In this case something like www.mysite.com/VenuePage?Name="Mikes" 
This argument would then be used to select blocks with Title "Mikes"

Can someone point me in the correct direction? I'm a bit new to Drupal and may be thinking about this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the entity title of the row is a field on the view you can use the *Override the output of this field as a custom link* option and then create a link yourself using replacement patterns. So long as the field you are referencing the entity title of is beneath the field you are referencing in the field list.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly what to type in the "Link path" text box to make this happen. I can't seem to find an example that spells it out in Drupal 8.

Comment: There should be an available replacement patterns dropdown. If not, that dropdown is definitely available in the _Override the output of this field as custom text_ option. And then you can write the `<a>` tag yourself.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the `Rewrite results` fieldset you should see another fieldset called `Replacement patterns`, in it there will be a list of available patterns (examples from the Files view):

- {{ fid }} ==
- {{ filename }} ==
- {{ filemime }} ==
- {{ filesize }} == File size
- {{ filesize__value }} == Raw value

**NOTE:** You will only see values from fields above the one you are rewriting. In my example I was rewriting `filesize`, if I had done `mime`, then `filesize` wouldn't be in the list.

For your path, you would have something like `/VenuePage?name={{ field_name_of_field }}`

If the `VenuePage` is a view too, then you can add a `Contextual filter` to it, removing the need for parameters, and then your URL would be:

```
/VenuePage/{{ field_name_of_field }}
/VenuePage/Mikes
```